# Close popups created with window.open in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have Ie 11 to support. I open the popup using `var myWindow = window.open('url','name','width=640,height=480,menubar=no,toolbar=no');`

however, the handle returned (`myWindow`) is always null in ie.

I need to close that popup after certain events happen.
I know that it is possible because I've seen other sites do that in the same browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't be `null`. The only reason I think it would be null is if you are blocking popups in IE. Check for settings in IE where you can unblock popups then try again.

Answer (score 1):

If [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) is returning `null`, then something is wrong. You're likely blocking popups, which means that the [`Window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) will not be created (and thus `myWindow` will be `null`).

Check your security settings there and enable them.

Once you get `window.open()` to execute successfully, you can call [`myWindow.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close) to close the popup when necessary. Note that the `close()` method can only close popups that have been opened using the `window.open()` method.